# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: AbstractHttpContent.class

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, gradle, google-play-services

I'm getting the duplicate entry error for abstractHttpContent.class which is part of app engine.

I'm using google app engine backend. I also have multidex enabled, without multidex it give me an method exceeded error.

here is my app gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.joseph.googlesign_in"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
    compile project(path: ':gsiBackend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    compile project(':gsiBackend')
}
```

Here is my backend gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.18'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'appengine'

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints:1.9.18'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-endpoints-deps:1.9.18'
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
}

appengine {
    downloadSdk = true
    appcfg {
        oauth2 = true
    }
    endpoints {
        getClientLibsOnBuild = true
        getDiscoveryDocsOnBuild = true
    }
}
```

The location of [abstractHttpContent.class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNeLg.jpg)

It seems the error started after adding google play services to use google sign in.
Has anyone encountered this build error? Any advice on how to fix it?
Thanks

Comment: I believe `Google play services 8.3` made some changes on the google signin system. You can check out here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#november_2015_-_v83, and I suggest that you can try to use version 8.1.

Comment: Thank you, your comment helped me find the solution. I'm going to submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discuss, I believe `Google play services 8.3` made some changes on the google signin system. You can check out here: 
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#november_2015_-_v83

So I suggest that you can try to use `version 8.1`.

The issue was with google play services.
Here is top level gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Change the following
From

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
```

To

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0'
```

Also the aapt.exe was timing out and displaying an error.
Ran the appt.exe file to make sure it was running and everything seems to be working now.

Tried to run the app with mulidex disabled and it still works

Comment: I have same error but for below android version-5, I did whatever changes you suggested. please take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645868/for-below-android-version-5-i-am-getting-zipexception-with-duplicate-entry-com

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with google play services.
Here is my top level gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Change the following
From

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
```

To

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0'
```

Also the aapt.exe was timing out and displaying an error.
I ran the appt.exe file to make sure it was running and everything seems to be working now.

I also tried to run the app with mulidex disabled and it still works