# For below android version-5 i am getting ZipException with duplicate entry: com/google/api/client/http/AbstractHttpContent.class

Tags: android, duplicates, build.gradle, android-4.4-kitkat

Not able to install app in android version 4.4 I am getting error like:

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
    > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/api/client/http/AbstractHttpContent.class
```

I have tried  [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33929298/java-util-zip-zipexception-duplicate-entry-abstracthttpcontent-class) but it didn't worked for me.

Here is my app dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'

    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.20.0'

    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.13.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile project(':library')
    compile project(':facebook-android-sdk-4.8.1')
}
```

dependencies for library module

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0'
}
```

Comment: Are you using com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.20.0 and com.google.code.gson:gson both?

Comment: yes, should i not use both ? if not which one ?

Comment: there are 2 implementation of AbstractHttpContent class in your code. In the dependency somewhere. What is in library module?

Comment: library module is for some custom views. there is no issue is building the app but not able install.

Comment: can you please include all your dependencies in the answer. com.google.http-client has been used twice. check your jars in libs and library module both.

Comment: I have updated the question, actually it was working fine before I upgraded  android studio to version 2.

Comment: try cleaning build. If still doesn't  work, invalidate cache, restart and run again.

Comment: not working ... there is message while building "Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android."  .what it means ?

Comment: org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient: are you using this jar?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068387/dependency-apache-http-client-in-android-with-google-apis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109257/discussion-between-pr38y-and-harry-mad).

Comment: am also getting same error , don't know how to fix it